# How to handle columns with categorical data and many unique values

Tags: machine-learning, data, categorical-data, encoding

I have a column with categorical data with nunique 3349 values, in a 18000k row dataset, which represent cities of the world.

I also have another column with 145 nunique values that I could also use in my model that represents product category.

Can I use one hot encoding to these columns or there's a problem with that solution?
Like which is the max number of unique values to use one hot encoding so there's not gonna be any problem ?

Can you point me to the right direction if I should use another encoding also?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For categorical columns, you have two options :

1. Entity Embeddings
2. One Hot Vector

For a column with 145 values, I would use one hot encoding and Embedding for ~3k values. This decision might change depending on overall number of features.

Embeddings map feature values into a 1D vector so that model knows NYC, Paris, London are similar cities in one aspect (size) and very different in other aspects.  So, instead of using ~3k column of features, model will have ~50 columns of vector representation.

Articles that explain Embeddings :

- [An Overview of Categorical Input Handling for Neural Networks](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-overview-of-categorical-input-handling-for-neural-networks-c172ba552dee)
- [On learning embeddings for categorical data using Keras](https://medium.com/@satnalikamayank12/on-learning-embeddings-for-categorical-data-using-keras-165ff2773fc9)
- [Google Developers > Machine Learning > Embeddings: Categorical Input Data](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/embeddings/categorical-input-data)
- [Exploring Embeddings for Categorical Variables with Keras by Florian Teschner](http://flovv.github.io/Embeddings_with_keras/)